# How do I get ActiveRecord to use data from joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm running this ActiveRecord statement

```
@items = Item.joins(:order => :person)
             .select('items.*').select('orders.*')
             .includes(:order => [:person, :organization])
             .order('created_at DESC')
             .limit(10)
```

And these are the queries:

```
SELECT items.*, orders.* FROM items INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = items.order_id INNER JOIN people ON  people.id = orders.person_id WHERE items.deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
Item Load (0.001ms) 

SELECT (trace)
SELECT orders.* FROM orders WHERE orders.deleted_at IS NULL AND orders.id IN (51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46) ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC
Order Load (0.000ms) 

SELECT (trace)
SELECT people.* FROM people WHERE people.deleted_at IS NULL AND people.id IN (11, 22, 21, 19, 18)
Person Load (0.000ms)  

SELECT (trace)
SELECT organizations.* FROM organizations WHERE organizations.id IN (1)
Organization Load (0.000ms)
```

Why is ActiveRecord re-selecting data from the database if it was already SELECT'd using an INNER JOIN in the first `SELECT items.*, orders.*` query? How can I get it to hydrate item.order without going back to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Hi when using ActiveRecord joins it always finding a matching data between your relational model.

Example: 
If Person has many Items and Items belongs to Person the activerecord query would be:

```
Item.find(:all, :joins => :person, :select => "items.name, persons.full_name", :conditions => ["persons.full_name = ?", 'Allen', :order => "persons.created_at DESC"])
```

The above code returns all item name and person's full name where full name = 'Allen' and orders to created_at DESC or persons table. So there would be many INNER JOIN queries in your logs when Person's id is equals to Item's person_id column.